# Spotify opens a new window when you click on the sound tray menu [Loki]

Tags: release-loki, sound, wingpanel, spotify

When you use new Loki's Menu to control Spotify, and click on the spotify song, a new window opens each time you click instead of bringing the existing window to the foreground. 
see here:   [http://i.imgur.com/RBYDbee.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/RBYDbee.gifv)

Answer (score 1):

This application acts against common expectations, so I'd consider it a bug. Please [subscribe to the **bug report** here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-sound/+bug/1629761) so that the devs can ask for help testing solutions. If you want to give the open source devs some extra incentive, try putting [a developer bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary/bounties) on the task.